# Eclipse Link using wrong field mapping in InheritanceType.JOINED inherited classes

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, eclipselink, jpql

I have an Animal class which is extended by two classes:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name="class_animal")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=31)
@DiscriminatorValue("animal")
@Cacheable
@Cache(coordinationType=CacheCoordinationType.INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS, alwaysRefresh=true, expiry=300)
public class Animal {
    @Id @Column(name="uuid")        private String id;
    @Column(name="owner")           private String owner;
    @Column(name="name")            private String name;
    @Column(name="type")            private String type;
}
```

The Cat class extending Animal

```
@Entity
@Table(name="class_animal_cat")
@Cacheable
@Cache(coordinationType=CacheCoordinationType.INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS, alwaysRefresh=true, expiry=300)
@DiscriminatorValue("cat")
public class Cat extends Animal {
    // ...
}
```

The Mouse class, extending the Animal

```
@Entity
@Table(name="class_animal_mouse")
@Cacheable
@Cache(coordinationType=CacheCoordinationType.INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS, alwaysRefresh=true, expiry=300)
@DiscriminatorValue("mouse")
public class Mouse extends Animal {
    // ...
}
```

I use following (simplified) syntax to receive all Animals:

```
ExpressionBuilder builder = new ExpressionBuilder(Animal.class);
ReadAllQuery databaseQuery = new ReadAllQuery(type, builder);
Expression exp = builder.getField("owner").equal("Thomas");
databaseQuery.setSelectionCriteria(exp);
Query query = ((JpaEntityManager)em.getDelegate()).createQuery(databaseQuery);
List<Animal> resultsList = query.getResultList();
```

As long as no items are in the DB, everything is fine and I get back an empty list.

If I add an item of type "Cat" I get following error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'owner'.
Error Code: 207
Call: SELECT t0.uuid, t0.type, t0.name, t0.owner, t1.uuid FROM class_animal t0, class_animal_cat t1 WHERE ((t1.owner = ?) AND ((t1.uuid = t0.uuid) AND (t0.type = ?)))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Animal sql="SELECT DISTINCT type FROM class_animal WHERE (owner = ?)")
```

The field accessor to `t1.owner` is wrong - `t0.owner` would be right. How can I configure/anotate the field to always fall back to Animal.owner instead of i.E. Cat.owner?

Comment: More information is needed to find out why it thinks there is a owner field in the class_animal_cat table.  Do you have multiple mappings to the owner field?  This also looks like you are using Native EclipseLink api for what seems a simple JPA query - does the same occur with a simple JPQL "select a from Animal a where a.owner = :yourValue"?

Comment: The same happens, when using a JPQL. It's a rather complex project and I'm not sure if I oversimplified the example, but this is basically all going on which could affect the EclipseLink part..

Comment: I actually found a solution/workaround for this but I'm still evaluating if this has sideeffects. In the `ReadAllQuery databaseQuery...` I set tthe setShouldOuterJoinSubclasses to true (`databaseQuery.setShouldOuterJoinSubclasses(true);`) - the query now works. However, I''m not sure if this is the correct way doing it.

Comment: side effects are that all subclass tables are joined into a single query.  Without this, you will see multiple queries - the first is on the root table to determine which classes are involved, the rest are on the specific subclasses that should be returned.  There will be performance impact depending on your database, the query etc, but for the most part, using the outer join will allow using pagination and ordering.

Comment: Alternatively for using `setShouldOuterJounSubclasses(true)` following annotation worked, as well:
`
public class Animal {
    @Id @Column(name="uuid")        private String id;
    @Column(name="owner")           private String owner;
    @Column(name="name")            private String name;
    @Column(name="type")            private String type;
}
`